# verbless sentence in advertising

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

Is it common in English advertising to include sentences without verbs like the following?

30-day no-hassle refunds available.

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the advertiser is just dropping the "to be" verb, which is merely a linking verb.

> "30-day, no-hassle refunds **(are)** available."

Newspapers usually drop verbs (usually "to be") and conjunctions (usually "and") in their titles as well.

Comment: Btw, is it preferable to put a comma after "30-day"?

Comment: I put it there to separate the adjectives. In proper English, when there are multiple adjectives collocated (next to each other), one usually puts commas to separate them (99% of the time, but not always). I don't think an advertiser would put one here, however, because it detracts from his big sale. He wants the customer to see the connection between 30-day and no-hassle; however, in correct English, in this situation, yes, there should be a comma. Would an advertiser put one there? Probably not.

Comment: @Apollyon - Please don't expect advertisers to follow the same style guidelines and grammatical rules that journalists or editors might use. Sometimes brevity is valued above all else.